# knitr render missing labels in ggplots

Tags: r, docker, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

I am containerizing the software needed for a Snakemake pipeline. Included in this is an R 4.0.2 installation plus Tidyverse and some Bioconductor packages (all via Conda Forge). Mostly everything seems to work, however, one step renders an .Rmd document via `knitr::render`. The document render runs without error, but the ggplot image in the HTML is missing all labels:

[image]

When I've run this code in a Conda environment on the same machine, it works fine. I suspect there is some library needed for rendering text in images that needs to be installed in the Docker container. **Has anyone experienced this before? Is there a specific library I need to add to the container to resolve this?**

[The container image](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/mfansler/scutr-quant) is public, if someone wants to test with it.

---

### Additional Info

#### Session Info

Here is the `sessionInfo()` output from the rendered HTML.

```
## R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
## Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
## 
## Matrix products: default
## BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/conda/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.10.so
## 
## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
##  [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
## [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
##  [1] cowplot_1.1.0   magrittr_1.5    forcats_0.5.0   stringr_1.4.0  
##  [5] dplyr_1.0.2     purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.1.2    
##  [9] tibble_3.0.3    ggplot2_3.3.2   tidyverse_1.3.0 Matrix_1.2-18  
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] tidyselect_1.1.0 xfun_0.18        haven_2.3.1      lattice_0.20-41 
##  [5] colorspace_1.4-1 vctrs_0.3.4      generics_0.0.2   htmltools_0.5.0 
##  [9] yaml_2.2.1       blob_1.2.1       rlang_0.4.7      pillar_1.4.6    
## [13] withr_2.3.0      glue_1.4.2       DBI_1.1.0        dbplyr_1.4.4    
## [17] modelr_0.1.8     readxl_1.3.1     lifecycle_0.2.0  munsell_0.5.0   
## [21] gtable_0.3.0     cellranger_1.1.0 rvest_0.3.6      evaluate_0.14   
## [25] knitr_1.30       fansi_0.4.1      broom_0.7.1      Rcpp_1.0.4.6    
## [29] scales_1.1.1     backports_1.1.10 jsonlite_1.7.1   farver_2.0.3    
## [33] fs_1.5.0         hms_0.5.3        digest_0.6.25    stringi_1.5.3   
## [37] grid_4.0.2       cli_2.0.2        tools_4.0.2      crayon_1.3.4    
## [41] pkgconfig_2.0.3  ellipsis_0.3.1   xml2_1.3.2       reprex_0.3.0    
## [45] lubridate_1.7.9  assertthat_0.2.1 rmarkdown_2.4    httr_1.4.2      
## [49] rstudioapi_0.11  R6_2.4.1         compiler_4.0.2
```

Comment: [This github issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/r-base-feedstock/issues/91) might be relevant.

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy that was exactly the issue - very much appreciated! They give multiple solutions there, but I posted one which I think is generic.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The GitHub issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/r-base-feedstock/issues/91) that @ManavalanGajapathy pointed out in a comment is identical to what I experienced. In summary, the Miniconda3 (Debian-based) Docker container I start with does not include fonts that R can use in plotting. The thread discusses multiple options for installing fonts both at a Docker-level (apt-get) and a Conda-level.

The solution I ended up choosing was to add the dependency `fonts-conda-ecosystem` to my Conda environment. The final output is now:

[image]